# ¿Como puedo obtener la latitud y longitud de un dispositivo?

Tags: c#, windows, geolocalización

Como puedo obtener la latitud y longitud de un dispositivo, deseo obtener los datos de geolocalización de un dispositivo desde una aplicacion de consola en C# y para ello use el método  `GeoCoordinateWatcher();` y funciona solo si el dispositivo tiene GPS, si el dispositivo no tiene GPS no envía datos, intente hacerlo con alguna `API` que me retornaba Latitud y longitud pero la discordancia es mucha y no me trae el dato exacto, se me ocurrió que se podría obtener la ubicación desde el navegador, la pregunta es ¿Como puedo obtener la ubicación desde el navegador?

Comment: La ubicación desde el navegador requiere que el usuario consienta a proporcionarla si no me equivoco. Lo que se suele hacer en estos casos es obtener la ip, y utilizar algun servicio de geolocalización por ip para obtenerla.

Comment: Pasa que los servicios de geolocalizacion cogen la IP publica y te proporcionan no los datos de localización tuyos sino los de la entidad que te proporciona el servicio de Internet,  en dado caso de que el usuario proporcione la localización, como podría traer ese dato?

Comment: Echa un vistazo a [esto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API)